# GCC: Linker error message contains no actual error

Tags: gcc, linker, g++, ld

I'm trying to get a sample program from the [RED SDK](https://www.red.com/developers) to work, but it won't link; g++ returns the following unhelpful output:

```
g++-4.9     -o dist/Debug/GNU_GCC4.9-Linux/red_sdk_poc build/Debug/GNU_GCC4.9-Linux/main.o -L../../libraries/R3DSDKv7_0_8/Lib/linux64 -L../../libraries/R3DSDKv7_0_8/Redistributable/linux -lR3DSDK -l:REDR3D-x64.so
../../libraries/R3DSDKv7_0_8/Lib/linux64/libR3DSDK.a(libR3DSDK.a-master.o): In function `R3DSDK::DynamicLibrary::getSymbols(bool, ...) const':
../../libraries/R3DSDKv7_0_8/Lib/linux64/libR3DSDK.a(libR3DSDK.a-master.o): In function `R3DSDK::DynamicLibrary::getSymbol(bool, void**, char const*) const':
../../libraries/R3DSDKv7_0_8/Lib/linux64/libR3DSDK.a(libR3DSDK.a-master.o): In function `R3DSDK::DynamicLibrary::unload(std::string&)':
../../libraries/R3DSDKv7_0_8/Lib/linux64/libR3DSDK.a(libR3DSDK.a-master.o): In function `R3DSDK::DynamicLibrary::unload(std::string&)':
../../libraries/R3DSDKv7_0_8/Lib/linux64/libR3DSDK.a(libR3DSDK.a-master.o): In function `R3DSDK::DynamicLibrary::~DynamicLibrary()':
../../libraries/R3DSDKv7_0_8/Lib/linux64/libR3DSDK.a(libR3DSDK.a-master.o): In function `R3DSDK::DynamicLibrary::~DynamicLibrary()':
../../libraries/R3DSDKv7_0_8/Lib/linux64/libR3DSDK.a(libR3DSDK.a-master.o): In function `R3DSDK::DynamicLibrary::~DynamicLibrary()':
../../libraries/R3DSDKv7_0_8/Lib/linux64/libR3DSDK.a(libR3DSDK.a-master.o): In function `R3DSDK::DynamicLibrary::~DynamicLibrary()':
../../libraries/R3DSDKv7_0_8/Lib/linux64/libR3DSDK.a(libR3DSDK.a-master.o): In function `R3DSDK::DynamicLibrary::load(std::string const&, std::string&)':
../../libraries/R3DSDKv7_0_8/Lib/linux64/libR3DSDK.a(libR3DSDK.a-master.o): In function `R3DSDK::DynamicLibrary::load(std::string const&, std::string&)':
../../libraries/R3DSDKv7_0_8/Lib/linux64/libR3DSDK.a(libR3DSDK.a-master.o): In function `R3DSDK::DynamicLibrary::load(std::string const&, std::string&)':
../../libraries/R3DSDKv7_0_8/Lib/linux64/libR3DSDK.a(libR3DSDK.a-master.o): In function `R3DSDK::DynamicLibrary::load(std::string const&, std::string&)':
../../libraries/R3DSDKv7_0_8/Lib/linux64/libR3DSDK.a(libR3DSDK.a-master.o): In function `R3DSDK::DynamicLibrary::getSymbol(std::string const&) const':
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As you can see, it only specifies a bunch of functions in the library, without any indication what might be the issue. Unfortunately, the SDK has just about most generic and ungoogleable name imaginable, and my attempts to find literally anything else about it have been fruitless, nor could I find anything about this sort of failure mode for ld.

Does anyone have any idea what I can do about these linker errors? If it helps, the SDK contains two sets of libraries, one under "Lib" containing .a files, and one under "Redistributable" containing .so files. I already tried linking both, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Looks like it might just be undefined references. Do you have your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` set to include the libs? What were your full compiler and linker commands?

Comment: It looks like that's indeed the issue. I was working in Netbeans, using a Linux machine as a remote host to do the actual compiling, and you comment gave me the idea to run the make command directly. Lo and behold, suddenly the "In function" lines are interspersed with "undefined reference to `dlsym'". Apparently, the new line caused Netbeans to miss the output. That'll teach me to doublecheck I suppose. Mind you, it's still not compiling, but now I got something to work eith. Thank for your time!